# How do I simplify discrete summation like the one given?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Prerequisite information:

Note that $u[n]$ is the [Heaviside or unit step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

$y_1[n] = x_1[n] * x_2[n[ $

$x_1[n] = (0.5)^n u[n] $

$x_2[n] = u[n+3]$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (0.5)^k \; u (n+3-k)$$

This evaluates to

$$
y_1(n) = x_1(n)*x_2(n) =
\begin{cases}
 2(1-(1/2)^{n+4}), & n \ge -3 \\ 
 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I know that a geometric summation of $(0.5)^n$ goes to $2$, but I don't understand the other term or how it is split up.

Comment: What is that $\,u[n+3-k]\,$ thing?

Comment: I think its the notation that it's using for a function of a value.

Comment: I edited your question to use $\LaTeX$, just check it to make sure I interpreted it correctly.

Comment: @AJMansfield, I guessed that: I was asking the OP for *what* that thing is, as it seems to be important to evaluate that sum. Your edit, BTW, had - instead + in the power of 0.5 almost at the end. Fix this and I'll approve your edit.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for the formating, and @DonAntonio, the first summation is just another way to write the convultion, and then they break it down to what you see in the second equation in that image

Comment: But what are these $u, y_1, x_1,$ and $x_2$?

Comment: Same question as the above comment, and it was AJMansfield who edited your post.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry about the confusion. I've added more information at the top of the post, and also $u$ is the Heaviside or unit step function

Comment: And, thank you @AJMansfield for the formatting.

Comment: The additional information is helpful, but it still doesn't explain what $u$ is, and without that it's hard to see how it's possible to evaluate that series.

Comment: I mentioned that in a comment here @Gerry-Myerson , it is the unit step function also known as the Heaviside function. Will add to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's compute $y_1(2)$ and see if that helps you see what's going on.

$$y_1(2)=\sum_0^{\infty}(1/2)^ku(5-k)=u(5)+(1/2)u(4)+(1/4)u(3)+(1/8)u(2)+(1/16)u(1)+(1/32)u(0)+\cdots$$ But this is $1+(1/2)+(1/4)+(1/8)+(1/16)+(1/32)$ because Heaviside is $1$ for nonnegative arguments, and zero for negative arguments. Those numbers add up to $1{31\over32}=2-{1\over32}=2(1-{1\over64})$, as required.

Now, do you see how to reproduce these calculations for other values of $n$?

Comment: I hope the OP can do the calculations as you suggested. +1